# Where Dalvik should be in new diagram?

Tags: android, architecture, dalvik, low-level

In which [layer](http://source.android.com/devices/index.html) does Dalvik go?

It is not mentioned anywhere in documentation.

[direct link to diagram](http://source.android.com/devices/images/system-architecture.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could say it's "under" the Applications and Framework layer and the stuff in the System Server box.

Dalvik isn't a service or a HAL, so it doesn't quite fit in that diagram.

Comment: As far as I understand, Dalvik is the runtime, pretty much like having a whole operating system running inside a JVM. People should now use call it the Android Runtime, because Dalvik is going to get replaced in the future by ART (Android RunTime). I'd say it's in between hardware and *software*

Comment: So if I understood well, that is a hardware only oriented diagram, while this one -> goo.gl/JYl7Ih is software oriented?

Comment: I don't think it's hardware vs. software.  The diagrams have a fairly similar view of the system.  In the diagram you linked in the question, they just chose not to call out the fact that some things run on top of Dalvik and some things run natively.